# What does the "a" after the selector ".topnav" do?

Tags: css

I am trying to replicate an navigation bar based off an example I saw. If someone could explain what it does that would be great.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WB0Y.png

```
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Answer (score 1):

It is an 'Descendant Selector', meaning it whatever is inside of 'topnav' class with the tag 'a' will be affected by the written css rules. You can refer to https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp for more information

Answer (score 1):

It targets the anchor inside the `topnav` element

```css
.topnav a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='topnav'>
  <a>I am the link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's basically the tag inside a HTML element with the class name topnav. Here's an example :

```
<div class="topnav">
  <a href="about.html">About</a>
</div>
```

You can see the " < a > " there, in your CSS code we use `.topnav a`, it's not the best term to use but we can say that the `.topnav a` just grabs the childs of the class topnav.